# custom hook useEffect issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I have 2 custom hooks. one is to handling token (useToken) and another is for just decoding user by token (useUser). Now I want updated token each time in my custom-hook useUser but it never triggers, I have added [token] as dependency but no useEffect call.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getToken() {
  return window.localStorage.getItem("token");
}
function useToken() {
  const [token, updateToken] = useState(() => getToken());

  const setToken = (newToken) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
    updateToken(newToken);
  };

  return [token, setToken];
}

const getUserFromToken = (token) => {
  if (!token) return null;
  return token + Date().toString();
};
function useUser() {
  const [token] = useToken();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getUserFromToken(token));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;

    const newUser = getUserFromToken(token);
    setUser(newUser);
  }, [token]);

  return user;
}

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useToken();
  const user = useUser();
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => setUserName(e.target.value);

  const saveHandler = () => {
    setToken(userName);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          value={userName}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={saveHandler}>Save</button>
      </div>
      <div>User - {user}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also tried by using useMemo instead useEffect in useUser hook but none of are working. Whats wrong going here?

Comment: What were you expecting and what did you get instead? *None are working* is not really an actionable problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to explain what's happening. Your custom hook `useUser` is using it's own *version* of the `useToken` hook. So when your actual token is updated inside `App` by calling `setToken`, it only updates the `token` inside the `App` component.

Notice the hook `useUser` still has its own version of the token even though you updated the token in `App`. Custom hooks don't magically talk to each other unless something like [useContext](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) is used.

The fix will be simple. We will pass the App's token to the `useUser` hook and everything will work.

```js
function useUser(token) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getUserFromToken(token));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;

    const newUser = getUserFromToken(token);
    setUser(newUser);
  }, [token]);

  return user;
}

// In App
const [token, setToken] = useToken();
const user = useUser(token);
```

---

I would however like to offer another piece of advice. I can see the `useUser` hook doesn't really do much. It basically processes whatever `token` it gets and spills out a `user` without performing any actions. For this use case, maintaining a separate state and using `useEffect` inside `useUser` seems to be unnecessary. Since `user` is always derived from the token this seems to a good case to use `useMemo`.
The `useUser` can thus be simplified as follows:

```js
function useUser(token) {
  const user = useMemo(() => getUserFromToken(token), [token]);
  return user;
}
```

I hope all of this made sense. :)